# Java random coords error?

Tags: java, compilation

I cannot seem to understand this error I'm getting. I've made a seperate class for random numbers, imported it and initiated it, but It say's I cannot use it?

```
Compiling loginserver...
src\com\rs2hd\net\ActionSender.java:745: sendCreateObject(int,int,int,int,int,in
t) in com.rs2hd.net.ActionSender cannot be applied to (int)
                        player.getActionSender().sendCreateObject(randomElement)
;
                                                ^

randomElement =
```

Comment: Without showing us your code, we really can't tell you what you're doing wrong. It appears you're trying to use two types of things that don't go together.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sendCreateObject` is declared to take 6 integers as arguments. In your line

```
player.getActionSender().sendCreateObject(randomElement)
```

you're only giving it *one*!

To give you an example, the code below gives the exact same error message:

```
public class Test {

    static void sendCreateObject(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sendCreateObject(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: So how would I get it to work, its loading 6 but randomElement is one loading 6?

Comment: What does "randomElement is one loading 6" mean?

Comment: `sendCreateObject` needs six numbers to do its job, just as telling a bank "transfer some money" needs (at least) two accounts and an amount. You're only giving it one number. That's like going into a bank and saying "I'd like to transfer $5,000" without saying *from* where or *to* where. Since you've told us nothing about what `sendCreateObject` actually does or what its arguments are, and nothing about where this `randomElement` number came from, we can't really tell you anything more specific about what you need to be doing.

Comment: sendCreateObject sends an object ID to designated coordinates on a game. What I mean by randomElement is one loading six is, Randomelement equals for example "32660, 0, 1337, 1264, 0, 10" but it's loading multiple different strings of different ones, 
ex: "32660, 0, 1337, 1264, 0, 10"
    "32660, 0, 2582, 9345, 0, 10"